# How to parse names from raw text

Tags: python, nlp, linguistics

I was wondering if anyone knew of any good libraries or methods of parsing names from raw text.

For example, let's say I've got these as examples: (note sometimes they are capitalized tuples, other times not)

```
James Vaynerchuck and the rest of the group will be meeting at 1PM. 
Sally Johnson, Jim White and brad burton. 
Mark angleman Happiness, Productivity & blocks. Mark & Evan at 4pm.
```

My first thought is to load some sort of Part Of Speech tagger (like Pythons NLTK), tag all of the words. Then strip out only nouns, then compare the nouns against a database of known words (ie a literal dictionary), if they aren't in the dictionary, assume they are a name.

Other thoughts would be to delve into machine learning, but that might be beyond the scope of what I need here.

Any thoughts, suggestions or libraries you could point me to would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: That wouldn't really work, because, after all, what is a name? You can name a child whatever you want, and, as such many names may be in the Dictionary. Some people might even be named after adjectives.

Comment: For more information on "what is a name", see [falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). And the comments (e.g., how you do deal with Prince, back when his name was a symbol that didn't even exist in Unicode?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need NLTK just to rule out dictionary words; a simple dictionary (which you might have installed somewhere like `/usr/share/dict/words`, or you can download one off the internet) is all you need:

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    dictwords = {word.strip() for word in f}
with open(mypath) as f:
    names = [word for line in f for word in line.rstrip().split()
             if word.lower() not in dictwords]
```

Your `words` list may include names, but if so, it will include them capitalized, so:

```
    dictwords = {word.strip() for word in f if word.islower()}
```

Or, if you want to whitelist proper names instead of blacklisting dictionary words:

```
with open('/usr/share/dict/propernames') as f:
    namewords = {word.strip() for word in f}
with open(mypath) as f:
    names = [word for line in f for word in line.rstrip().split()
             if word.title() in namewords]
```

But this really isn't going to work. Look at "Jim White" from your example. His last name is obviously going to be in any dictionary, and his first name will be in many (as a short version of "jimmy", as a common romanization of the Arabic letter "jīm", etc.). "Mark" is also a common dictionary word. And the other way around, "Will" is a very common name even though you want to treat it as a word, and "Happiness" is an uncommon name, but at least a few people have it.

So, to make this work even the slightest bit, you probably want to combine multiple heuristics. First, instead of a word being either always a name or never a name, each word has a probability of being used as a name in some relevant corpus—White may be a name 13.7% of the time, Mark 41.3%, Jim 99.1%, Happiness 0.1%, etc. Next, if it's not the first word in a sentence, but is capitalized, it's much more likely to be a name (how much more? I don't know, you'll need to test and tune for your particular input), and if it's lowercase, it's less likely to be a name. You could bring in more context—for example, you have a lot of full names, so if something is a possible first name and it appears right next to something that's a common last name, it's more likely to be a first name. You could even try to parse the grammar (it's OK if you bail on some sentences; they just won't get any input from the grammar rule), so if two adjacent words only work as part of a sentence one if the second one is a verb, they're probably not a first and last name, even if that same second word could be a noun (and a name) in other contexts. And so on.

Comment: Great approach, I wasn't aware of of the words file in /usr/share/dict/. I do notice that it contains words like Abby, etc. so maybe just blacklisting words from the dict won't be a complete solution as described above. I like your heuristic approach, I'll report back when I've given that a go.

Comment: @Blakedallen: Depending on your platform (or the third-party dict you've downloaded), your `words` file may have all proper nouns capitalized and all common nouns lowercased, which means the `if word.islower()` will take care of that problem. There are still limits to how useful it is; most platforms use an early-20th century dictionary (typically Webster's 1934) for copyright reasons, and obviously that won't cover many newer words, but you can download a later or otherwise more appropriate corpus and extract the words for similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library quite useful for parsing names: [Python Name Parser](https://code.google.com/p/python-nameparser/)

It can also deal with names that are formatted Lastname, Firstname.